# How to "disable" a Java object?

Tags: java, database, invalidation

I have a class like this:

```
public class DatabaseSession {

  public makeCallOne() {...}
  public makeCallTwo() {...}
  public close() { ... }

}
```

If the user instantiates this class, I expect them to be able to call makeCallOne and makeCallTwo. However, if they call close(), then any subsequent calls to makeCallOne() or makeCallTwo() should return an exception.

I could do this with an if statement at the top of each method, but that's easy to forget to write. What standard mechanism is used for saying "This object is useless now. You can't call it anymore."?

Comment: As you say, use a state flag, check its state at the beginning of the method and throw an exception as required. Any technique I can think off works basically the same way, check, run/throw

Comment: Instead of writing an if statement at the beginning of every method you could just write the if statement in a private method and call that.

Comment: @Ozzie - and throw the exception from in there too. It could then be called something like `ensureOpen()`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Thats exactly what i meant :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no disabling call in the java class library.

You should create a `State` enum and check it at the beginning of every method as defensive programming. Your class then becomes a finite state machine where you do certain things in certain states. So you may be instantiated, then opened, and then closed, etc. This information can be encoded in a `State` enum, which is flexible and open to change going forward.

For instance,

```
public class DatabaseSession {
    private State state;

    ...


    public makeCallOne() throws Exception {
        if (state == State.CLOSED)) {
            throw new Exception("Database Session has already been closed");
        }
        ...
    }
    public makeCallTwo() throws Exception {
        if (state == State.CLOSED)
            throw new Exception("Database Session has already been closed");
        }
        ...
    }

    public close() {
        state = State.CLOSED;
        ...
    }

    private enum State {
        OPEN;
        CLOSED;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The owner lets it go out of scope.  That's the standard mechanism.  Then you write the if statement anyway inside of all the makeCall functions, as defensive programming (you can argue for an assert instead, depending on philosophy).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can only do something like that using a flag, you could however place the if statement in a validation method. Like so:

```
public class DatabaseSession {

    private boolean closed = false;

    private void validateSession() {
        if(closed) {
            throw new ObjectInvalidException();
        } 
    }

    public void makeCallOne() { 
        validateSession();
        /*do something*/ 
    }
    public void makeCallTwo() { 
        validateSession();
        /*do something*/
    }

    public void close() {
        closed = true;
    }
}
```

I would define my own exception (extend `Throwable`).

Comment: `validateSession` probably should be `private`.

Comment: you don't need to initialize field "closed".

Comment: @OldCurmedgeon Yea it should be private, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

You can use any instance specific flag which will be turned ON (true) when object is created, and set it to OFF(false) when close method is called on that object. You can always check the value of the flag and throw an exception if it is OFF(set to false i.e. it indicates that objects close method is invoked).

Hope this helps.